# HttpResponseRedirect not working in django

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

HttpResponseRedirect not working it shows error as 'context must be dict rather than response'

```
class FooterLinksView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pages/footerlinks.html'
    model = FooterLink

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super(FooterLinksView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        string_name = self.kwargs['string']
        obj = FooterLink.objects.get(link_url=string_name)

        if obj.link_type == 'page':
            try:
                context['page_obj'] = obj
                return context
            except:
                pass
        else:
            pass
            print(obj.url_name)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(str(obj.url_name))
```

Answer (score 1):

`get_context_data()` is the method for return context, so it must return `context` object. If you want to redirect, do it in `get()`.

like below

class FooterLinksView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pages/footerlinks.html'
    model = FooterLink

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    string_name = self.kwargs['string']
    obj = FooterLink.objects.get(link_url=string_name)

    if obj.link_type != 'page':
        return HttpResponseRedirect(str(obj.url_name))
    else:
        return super().get(*args, **kwargs)
        # if python2
        # return super(FooterLinksView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super(FooterLinksView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    string_name = self.kwargs['string']
    obj = FooterLink.objects.get(link_url=string_name)

    if obj.link_type == 'page':
        try:
            context['page_obj'] = obj
            return context
        except:
            pass
    return context
```

or you can just use `extra_context` in `TemplateView`.

class FooterLinksView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'pages/footerlinks.html'
    model = FooterLink

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    string_name = self.kwargs['string']
    obj = FooterLink.objects.get(link_url=string_name)

    if obj.link_type != 'page':
        try:
            self.extra_context = {
                'page_obj': obj
            }
        except:
            pass
        return HttpResponseRedirect(str(obj.url_name))
    else:
        return super().get(*args, **kwargs)
        # if python2
        # return super(FooterLinksView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Overriding `get` is bad practice as the request can be a `post` too. It is best to stick to `dispatch` as it works for all HTTP methods.

Comment: @Selcuk I think you're right if using `View`. But in `TemplateView`, isn't there no `post` method?

Comment: error " dispatch() got an unexpected keyword argument 'string' "

Comment: @seuling You are right, I was talking about the best practices in general, not for this specific instance.

Comment: @Selcuk Right. I usually do this in get or post, but I'll try using `dispatch` for general usage. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must always return a `dict` from your `get_context_data` function. If you want to redirect, you should override `dispatch` too:

```
class FooterLinksView(TemplateView):
    ...
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        string_name = self.kwargs['string']
        obj = FooterLink.objects.get(link_url=string_name)
        if obj.link_type != 'page':
            return HttpResponseRedirect(str(obj.url_name))
        return super(FooterLinksView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(FooterLinksView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        string_name = self.kwargs['string']
        obj = FooterLink.objects.get(link_url=string_name)
        context['page_obj'] = obj
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

The code in your `get_context_data` is trying to retrieve a single object and passing it to the context dictionary. This functionality is already built-in the [`DetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) and seems to be a better fit here than the [`TemplateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview).

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class FooterLinksView(DetailView):
    model = FooterLink
    template_name = 'pages/footerlinks.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()

        if self.object.link_type == 'page':
            context = self.get_context_data(object=self.object)
            return self.render_to_response(context)

        return HttpResponseRedirect(str(obj.url_name))
```

Now the only thing we need to add is how the `FooterLink` object is retrieved in the `get_object` method. If your `link_url` field of `FooterLink` is the primary key we can simply add `pk_url_kwarg = 'link_url'` in the top of the class. Otherwise you should use the `slug_field` and `slug_url_kwarg`.

```
class FooterLinksView(DetailView):
    model = FooterLink
    pk = 'link_url'             # if link_url is the primary key
    slug_field = 'link_url'     # if link_url is not the primary key
    slug_url_kwarg = 'string'   # if link_url is not the primary key
    template_name = 'pages/footerlinks.html'

    ...
```

Note: You should now use the `object` variable inside your template (instead of `obj`) or override yet another option: `context_object_name`.

Answer (score -1):

```
class FooterLinksView(TemplateView):                                
    template_name = 'pages/footerlinks.html'                        
    model = FooterLink                                              

    def get(self, request, args, *kwargs):                        

        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)                   
        string_name = self.kwargs['string']                         
        obj = get_object_or_404(FooterLink, link_url=string_name)   

        if obj.link_type == 'page':                                 
           context['page_obj'] = obj                               

           return render(request, self.template_name, context)     
        else:                                                       
            a = obj.url_name                                        
            return HttpResponseRedirect(a)
```